# Download 1 sheet from Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, export, download

I've got a spreadsheet (workbook) in Google Drive Sheets that has multiple sheets (tabs/worksheets).

I want to export just one worksheet from the workbook as an XLS file.

Is this possible?

I know I can download the entire file as an XLS and then delete the worksheets I don't need, but this is quite long-winded. I also know I could download just my current worksheet as a CSV, but in doing this I would lose all formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution I found was to right click the sheet in the bottom bar `copy to > new spreadsheet`.
This will create a new spreadsheet containing just this tab. Just make sure to delete this new spreadsheet when you are done as this can get confusing as you are essentially duplicating your data.

Answer (score 13):

I'm aware this was asked some months ago but this recently became a part of my weekly workflow and I decided there had to be a better answer than the roundabout answers that were given.

My solution is admittedly a little hacky but it has worked for me and, barring any future changes Google plans to make in how they encode their URLs, should work for the foreseeable future.

It turns out, per Dafne Canales Lees' answer to [a similar question asked on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-download-just-one-sheet-from-Google-spreadsheet), that **all you have to do is replace the `"/edit#gid="` part of the URL with `"/export?format=xlsx&gid="`**

This works just fine although I did find that I had to keep looking up this string and copying it. Instead, I made a quick Javascript snippet that does all the work for you:

**Just create a new bookmark name it whatever you like and add this as the URL for the bookmark. Then, whenever you need to export a single page sheet from Google Sheets as an Excel document, just open the page you want to export, click that bookmark, and it should start the download.**

`javascript:var%20winURL%20=%20window.location.href;if(winURL.indexOf('/edit#gid=')%20%3E%200)%7Bwindow.location.assign(winURL.replace('/edit#gid=',%20'/export?format=xlsx&gid='));%7Delse%7Balert('Incorrect%20URL%20format');%7D`

I've tested this on the latest versions of Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. They all work although you might have to get a little creative about how you make your bookmarks.

Comment: A very welcomed solution :)

Comment: If you need to download it as a pdf (like me), you can use `pdf` instead of `xlsx` for the `format` param. So it will be like: `.../export?format=pdf&grid=...`.

Answer (score 2):

I have wrote a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-this-gsheet/ilpfikjnjieiinbnnbfabncjdjpgbfbm?hl=en&authuser=0) doing exactly this, the solution is exactly the same with Dave Feldt's comment, all you need is click on the extension and it will download the current active tab for you.

Answer (score 1):

That's not really a thing, but best you can do is to download it as **.tsv** file and then just open it in Notepad and copy-paste it into Excel. Of course, the formatting gets lost.

[image: 0]